# Fragment initialized without onCreate being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

So I have a fragment inside a viewpager which is contained inside a fragment which is getting initialize'd as shown in the debugger but doesn't have it's onCreate,onCreateView or any such methods being called. The activity containing has a bottom navigation view and contains 4 such fragments and this issue is only happening in 1 such fragment.

All these fragments and viewpagers and fragments inside them are created on the oncreate of the activity. If I move the logic to create the fragment to when a bottom tab is clicked, this issue gets solved on.

How is this possible ?

Comment: you should show ur code, hard to find out problem without it

Comment: Check onCreateView() method

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil Even onCreateView isn't called for the fragment inside

Comment: Can you please provide code where you set viewpager and fragments,and any code you think might be causing problems please post here so that we can help you better.

Comment: can you please send us some code?

Answer (score 1):

Only the currently active fragment and the two directly adjecant fragments are created when the viewpager is first shown. so the fragment for the first page, the fragment for the page shown if you "scroll to the left" and the fragment for the page shown when you "scroll to the right". the 4th fragment will be created when it is put in the next adjecant position.

so if you have fragments a,b,c,d in a viewpager like -a-[b]-c-d- where b is the first visible page, only a,b and c will be created at startup. when you scroll to c -a-b-[c]-d- onCreate for fragment d will be called.

Comment: I don't think you understood the issue. The page offset limit is more then the fragments so the 4 fragment did get called and is loaded. The fragment inside it only was initialised but the onCreate wasn't called.

Comment: what do you want to do by calling onCreate() of fragment before it is visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can control number of pages/fragments preloaded when you launch your activity by setting it's off Screen Page Limit on your view pager adapter. like this

- mViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(limit)

If you set limit to 0 than only first fragment would be load.

https://spotandroid.com/2016/11/23/android-tricks-viewpager-and-offscreen-tabs/

https://techcodegeek.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/android-viewpager-and-performance-improvements/

Answer (score 0):

Need more detail to know your issue.Issue which you are facing is not understood with information you have provided.